# split string into array then get element in 1 line

Tags: javascript, split

I usually do this:

```
var str = "hello_blue_world";
var arr = str.split("_");
var target = arr[1];
```

But since I don't need the `arr`, I noticed that I can do this:

```
var str = "hello_blue_world";
var target = str.split("_")[1];
```

My question:

1. Is this approach supported in different ECMAScript versions?
2. Is it safe to do this approach?

Comment: Yes it is safe, BTW do you have a PHP background by any chance?

Comment: Perfectly safe and supported on Chrome, Firefox (Gecko), Internet Explorer, Opera and Safari

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Yes I use PHP, but my question is purely about javascript

Comment: Thought so because PHP has only introduced [FAD](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing) in 5.4 and your question would be a bit more interesting if it was PHP. Oh back to the topic, this is safe in ES5 and ES3, that is, all versions you should care about.

Comment: @spassvogel please post your comment as an answer, since it's based on source and it answers my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes to both. It's safe and supported.

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.14

> Returns an Array object into which substrings of the result of converting this object to a String have been stored

If this is true your `str.split("_")` evaluates to array and you should be able to use `[x]` to get any of the returned elements.

Comment: shouldn't this be a comment?

Comment: I think your answer is correct, but it's not based on any source or demo or reference

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot: No, a question that makes sense deserves an answer. Even if that answer is short.

Answer (score 1):

Perfectly safe and supported on Chrome, Firefox (Gecko), Internet Explorer, Opera and Safari

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference